# Is code reuse possible in this scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-reuse, reusability

I have a Index page which shows data for current_user only, and I made another page which shows the same data fields and same format as of index page but not for current_user but after querying for some other column, in this case is it possible to reuse the code of index and using some condition in the controller to pass the object variable different in each case ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the controller is FoosController and the action of index page for current_user is #bar, then your controller may look like this

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def bar
    @user = current_user
  end
```

To reuse the template, you can make a separate partial template say `app/views/foos/_index.html.erb`.

Then, in `app/views/foos/bar.html.erb`

```
<%= render partial: '_index', locals: { user: @user }
```

To reuse the partial template in another action, you just need to call the partial in another template, feed it with different instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

You bet - `@user = params[:user_id] ? User.find( params[:user_id] ) : current_user`